# fix dependency Resolution error - Duplicate class error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, error-handling

```
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-23.4.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)
    
    Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.**strong text**
```

got this Error in Build will run the App

By Adding this Dependencies....

```
    implementation 'com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that some .jar libraries comes bundled with the dependencies that are already available locally. So by removing one of the newly added libraries can solve the problem... Find library that does not come with the dependencies that are already present, an or you can remove everything in the dependency section and add library only, sync project. And add other dependencies one by one..